# Unable to download data with tidyhydat

Tags: r, sqlite

I'm using [tidyhydat](https://docs.ropensci.org/tidyhydat/articles/tidyhydat_an_introduction.html) to download historical data on water flow from Environment Canada. I attempted to store the data in my own director (rather than the default) and received an error message.  However, I can clearly see the Hydat.sqlite3 file (~1.1 GB in my specified folder).

```
download_hydat(dl_hydat_here = "./Data_Covariates/Raw/")
✔ Downloading HYDAT to ./Data_Covariates/Raw/
• Your local copy of HYDAT published on 2022-10-24 will be overwritten.
  |==================================================================================================================================| 100%
• Extracting HYDAT
★ HYDAT successfully downloaded
Error in hy_src(hydat_path) : 
  No Hydat.sqlite3 found at C:/Users/[redacted]/AppData/Local/tidyhydat/tidyhydat. Run download_hydat() to download the database.
```

When I download it to the default directory I got same error message and I *don't* see the database in this folder:

```
download_hydat()
✔ Downloading HYDAT to C:\Users\[removed]\AppData\Local/tidyhydat/tidyhydat
• Downloading new version of HYDAT created on 2022-10-24
  |==================================================================================================================================| 100%
• Extracting HYDAT
✖ HYDAT not successfully downloaded
Error in hy_src(hydat_path) : 
  No Hydat.sqlite3 found at C:/Users/[redacted]/AppData/Local/tidyhydat/tidyhydat. Run download_hydat() to download the database.
In addition: Warning message:
In file.rename(list.files(tempdir, pattern = "\\.sqlite3$", full.names = TRUE),  :
  cannot rename file 'C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpCEBKiZ/extracted/Hydat.sqlite3' to 'C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local/tidyhydat/tidyhydat/Hydat.sqlite3', reason 'The system cannot find the path specified'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps related to [this](https://github.com/ropensci/tidyhydat/issues/187)? Try with dev version `remotes::install_github("ropensci/tidyhydat")`

Comment: @RicVillalba That worked for the default download_hydat() option.  For my personal directory, I needed to specify the whole file path, rather than the short form I used above.  If you want to write up an answer, I will accept it..  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Mine was a suggest. Must respond yourself with detail of what worked to you so it is available for other with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing to download the latest version of the package and from there I could get the download to work properly either using the default directory or by specifying the **whole** pathway to my personal directory.

```
remotes::install_github("ropensci/tidyhydat")
library(tidyhydat)

# OPTION 1: default directory
download_hydat()

# OPTION 2: personal directory
download_hydat(dl_hydat_here = "C:/Users/[redacted]/Analysis/Data_Covariates/Raw/")
```